# How do I kill the Phantasm boss that keeps multiplying?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

The final boss of Spirit Crucible Elpys is a phantasm that, whenever you get him down to 25% he goes invulnerable and multiplies. It seems there's a max of 6 at any given time. How do you kill him without him multiplying further?

Comment: I found Poppibuster to help with this fight *a lot* since you can attach him (her?) to one of your other drivers and still build up level 4 affinity in this zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to kill him by following a certain strategy:

When your current phantasm gets down to about 40% health, **stop attacking it** and target a different phantasm (using RB+Y or RB+A). The NPCs will finish the phantasm you're targeting off.

You should continue to do this until you're down to the last phantasm. I think once you get under a certain number of phantasms they stop multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up beating the fight by being slightly overleveled ,dogpiling ourselves into a corner and trying to take advantage of AoE arts. When we were down to about ~3 shadows left, trying to evenly whittle them each down to about ~40% health each with targetting, then starting a chain attack and trying to use AoE attacks to burst them all down.

Comment: Pro-tip: Poppibuster (available from DLC side quest) is a blade that you can put on Rex, Zeke, Nia, or Morag (and change drivers whenever you want - no overdrive needed) that is immune to the ether absorbing debuffs that your other blades are affected by. Poppibuster is a tank blade, but he(she?) also has some really nice AoE blade arts. I put him on Rex for this fight. So, some great AoE attacks from Poppi and Poppibuster allowed me to clean this up without chain attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Did this fight last night, lure them all into the poisonous water, they wont multiply when they are almost defeated. I found it out after 20 minutes of fighting and my tank fell down from the higher platform.

Comment: This is interesting. I'd need to see a video for this.

Answer (score -1):

SPOILER*
you gotta just keep fighting them... its part of the story.
they eventually stop multiplying

Comment: They actually do not. I was fighting them for approx. 30 minutes before employing my strategy (which I found by pure chance).

Comment: @Seiyria Theres plenty of articles around the net to back this up so perhaps both methods are possible?

Comment: @kenjara it's hard to say when there are no clear triggers or telegraphs.